# Why my codes showing during during runtime? (Django)

Tags: html, django

I just wanna ask what's wrong with my codes?

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
       <label><b>Lot Area: </b></label>
          <input type="text" id='lot_area' class="form-control" oninput="amount_calculate()" value="{{form.c_lot_area}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Django.

When I run it, the codes also display.
It always shows the double quotes and the right arrow during runtime.

Comment: [This exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69864927/1925257) was asked from a different account some time ago (now deleted). Anyway, you're setting  the value of the input to `{{ form.c_lot_area }}` which will return an HTML input field. Try using this: `value="{{ form.c_lot_area.value }}`.

Comment: yeah, thanks. It removes the double quotes and the right arrow but it cant save entered data in the input fields.